# Android - Signing certificate vs Upload Certificate

Tags: android

Hi i'm looking for some help on certificates for Android application.

Here is some background. The application:

1. Is on Google Playstore
2. Uses WeChat Login which authenticates against a signing key that i insert in the developer open platform
3. Is also distributed manually with APK (as Google is not available in China).

I am stuck because it seems the app uses two different certificates to sign. based on APK vs in the store.

- It appears the APK uses the signing certificate. But Google play
  store uses the upload certificate when the app ends up in the store.
  They are two different keys.
- But I can only key in 1 key into Wechat open platform (under 1
  application).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that Wechat open platform only supports 1 signing key under 1 application.

I recommend you to suggest Wechat team to consider supporting multiple signing key under 1 application. (Firebase already supports such a feature.)

And you have to choose which one is good for your benefit.

Comment: Oh. So i might be on the same page. Unfortunately, i can't even find the support link for Wechat! My only other alternative is, to create two different 'apps' in the Wechat open platform (they support that). One for the APK version and one for the store version. It also means i have to manage two different AppIds.. which is quite inefficient for now.